# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - Hidding the 'of X' in the pager bar where it says 'page Y ox X'

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In continues to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397929/free-jqgrid-4-8-0-setting-the-total-number-of-paging-post-grid-reload), I'm looking got a way to remove the "of X" part that is part of the pager 'page Y of X'.

So in case I'm working in a streaming mode, where I only know there is one more page ahead, without knowing how many real pages are waiting up front, I would prefer not to show "of X" which is not the true, but to only show the current page number.

Is there a built-in way I can show only the current page plus the next arrow?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All texts which you see in the grid can be localized. The corresponding templates come from `grid.locale-XX.js` files. You can open `grid.locale-en.js` file for example and search for `page`. You will find the property `pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}"` inside of `defaults` part (`$.jgrid.defaults`). The `defaults` settings are just the same options of jqGrid, but there are moved in locale files `grid.locale-XX.js` because of language specific texts.

Thus you can just add the option `pgtext: "Page {0}"` to jqGrid. There are one small problem in free jqGrid 4.8. It get all options (even the `defaults` part) from local file only. I [fixed](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/3d1ca2c1951cf4fde38163f69eff827e9349f4c4) the behavior in the current code on GitHub. So you should refresh the sources which you use. Alternatively you can set the option in the way

```
$.jgrid.defaults.pgtext = "Page {0}";
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/PageOf.htm) uses the the last sources from GitHub (`https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid`) and so it can use just `pgtext: "Page {0}"`. It display the pager like on the picture below

[image]

More interesting is the scenario which we discuss with you in comment to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30398778/315935). You wanted to return the data from the grid first and to get the information about the total number of records and pages *later* via separate Ajax call. The reason was: you need to get `COUNT(*)` from SELECT which produces very large results. Because of that getting one page is more quickly as getting `COUNT(*)`. In the scenario you want first hide the total number of records and to show the value later after the Ajax call for `COUNT(*)` will be finished. Using the scenario it would be consequent to *hide* the "of X'" part of the pager at the beginning and to show it later after the Ajax request for `COUNT(*)` will be finished.

I would suggest to use the following option

```
pgtext: "Page {0}<span class='pagerOf' style='display:none'> of {1}</span>"
```

in the scenario. The option will have the required information in the pager, but the information will be *hidden* initially. The `{1}` part pf the pager will be replaced with `<span>` having id which will be built based on the pager id using `sp_1_` prefix. It will allow you to show or to hide the "of ..." part of the pager any time.

[The next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/PageOfDynamic.htm) demonstrates the approach. It has two buttons which allows to show/hide the "of ..." part of the pager *dynamically*. You can use the same code inside of Ajax requests which you make. The last demo uses the following code

```js
var getPagerOf = function (grid) {
    var p = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"), sel = [];
    if (p.pager) {
        sel.push("#sp_1_" + p.pager.substr(1));
    }
    if (p.toppager) {
        sel.push("#sp_1_" + p.toppager.substr(1));
    }
    return $(sel.join()).closest(".pagerOf");
}
$("#showOfPager").button().click(function () {
    getPagerOf($grid).show();
});
$("#hideOfPager").button().click(function () {
    getPagerOf($grid).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, Great answer!  What If I want to control it based on gird id?  I have 2 grids on the same page, where for one I still want to leave the default as is.

Comment: Sorry,  just saw your comment regard the "fix".

Comment: @Tal: Yes, you should use the latest sources of free jqGrid from GitHub to be able to overwrite setting from `$.jgrid.defaults` part of locale file `grid.locale-XX.js`.